# in a single vector layer I have a three of polygons with different field values (e.g1,2,3). How Can I color each field value polygon differently?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2.8

In a single vector layer I have a three  of polygons with different field values (e.g1,2,3). How Can I color each field value polygon differently? 
To explain a bit more my three polygons are showing the levels of risks. I would like to demonstrate red color where ever the polygon field value is 3 and blue where is one.

I can show the polygons field attribute value (number as text) on the map using labels but can not use the value to illustrate different color for each field attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a Categorized (2.) symbology under Layer Properties -> Style (1.).

To define custom colours for every single value, you can classify (4.) the layer with the selected attribute column (3.). After the automatic classification, you can assign a different colour for every different field value by double clicking the coloured square under Symbol (5.), and choosing a colour in the popup window (6.). You have to repeat the process manually for every different value.

[image: class_process]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabor, really appreciated with well explained graphical snapshot.This saved me a lot of time. Highly appreciated.