# Colour specific polygons on a postcode map - QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am working on a UK postcode map. It only has the first bit of the postcode, e.g. BR12. I have an excel spreadsheet with the longitude/latitude of specific points as well as their postcodes. Instead of plotting points I'd like to colour the postcode in which they are located.

Manually selecting the postcodes to colour would be a huge waste of time. Has anyone got a suggestion on how to proceed?

As per @Jospeh's suggestion, I have decided to go for the Rule-Based option on my .shp -however I don't understand how to add a rule as proposed below.

[image]

Comment: You could use a **Rule-based** style on your postcode map with a rule like `"postcode_field" = 'BR12'` to colour specific polygons.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph - could I ask you where I can add such rule?

Comment: I see you already did it =). I suggest you post your [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/194711/revisions) as an **answer** as it sounds like it solved your problem.

Comment: Why not using just the Categorized style?http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20408/5193

Comment: @LauriK - That probably is a better method if the values are exact which seems to be in this question :). I'm biased as I prefer rule-based styles, which could be useful when you have full postcodes but want to give the same colour to each postcode area (e.g. `"postcode_field" LIKE 'BR12%'` would colour all polygons with postcodes starting with `BR12`.

Comment: @pdx - The button with the green plus sign (just above **Layer rendering**) lets you add rules which you can then add filters and set shapes, colours etc.

Comment: Last question: how do I write `"postcode" = 'B10' and 'B11'`?

Comment: `"postcode" in ('B10', 'B11')`

Answer (score 1):

After having browsed a bit on GIS, I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150587/in-a-single-vector-layer-i-have-a-three-of-polygons-with-different-field-values) thread v helpful.

I have added an indicator on my spreadsheet (where I have the lon/lat and postcodes).
Then I added the spreadsheet as a vector layer.
After that I double clicked on my shapefile > Joins > merged the data together.
I used this new merged data to colour selectively on "Categorized" as explained in the linked thread.